# Spring Retry performance

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-retry

I am using spring retry in my application, it works fine.
however, i am just concerning about if it will cause the performance issue if there are huge volume of retry

say one of the downstream service is down, and before it come back up, there are 1 million requests come in, then it will eat up all the resource for the service to do the normal operation.

is there any solution for this?

Comment: Look into Hystrix. It was designed to manage just this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

When millions of requests are expected in short time, spring-retry @CircuitBreaker can help to stop calling downstream system and will reduce performance impact.

```
   @CircuitBreaker(value = {RunTimeException.class},
            maxAttempts =  2,
            openTimeout = 2000L ,
            resetTimeout = 20000L) 
        public void myMethod(String aaa){
        retryTemplate.execute(args0 -> {
            // your business logic goes here
            return null;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It is just a opinion or suggestion to use `Spring-retry` (what i do in my case).

> 1. Recovery
> 2. backoff Policy.
> 3. retry Count.

`Spring-retry` enables user to define multiple retry method against different exception raised.

You should handle those exception accordingly.. like if a method having some severe exception then whether you should try or not (you should decide)..

> Suggestion ::The `@Recover` annotation is used to define a separate recovery method when a `@Retryable` method fails with a specified exception. You may store thing in database to process it further..

```
 @Recover
 void recover(SQLException e, String sql){ // Your Code of Handling...}
```

Now if you know that raised exception is able to handle in next retry then you should apply `BackOff` Policy. so that this can be handle accordingly..